# GridSearchCV semaphore or lock released too many times

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debian, semaphore, gridsearchcv

I developed my code on a Windows PC initially and everything ran fine. However, we have started to get loadshedding so I needed a portable python developing environment and so I setup a SLAX 9.8 usb with VSCode to continue my development when the power fails.

But now, when running the working code on the usb, it fails with this error:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

A quick Google search says it is a joblib error and to set prefer="threads". If that would solve it, where would I do that?

Thank you all